# GWT - define async services with a subclass of AsyncCallback

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

Does GWT allow to define the async services using a custom subclass of AsyncCallback?

Basically, I'd been suggested to do something similar to [How to wrap every Callback in one place to improve error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17401260/5511972) but do it in a way where the async service is defined using a custom subclass (or rather, a functional interface, with default error handling, as that would allow simple lambda usage).

In other words, when I have

```
public interface MyService extends RemoteService {
    Object doTheThing();
}
```

I'd like to replace

```
public interface MyServiceAsync {
    void doTheThing(AsyncCallback<Object> callback);
}
```

with

```
public interface MyServiceAsync {
    void doTheThing(MyCallback<Object> callback);
}
```

where MyCallback extends AsyncCallback.

This would be done in all the services and anything that needs refactoring would be refactored appropriately.

Currently doing so just produces errors `MyServiceAsync is missing method doTheThing(AsyncCallback<Object>)` on the class and `Last parameter must be of type AsyncCallback` on the method.

The question linked at the start is the only thing I could google up, everything else was about normal async service usage.

Comment: Yes, you can, but you have to write your own proxy, as the answer points out. Are you bound to RPC? If not, take a look at Dominokit/domino-rest ad GitHub. domino-rest has something similar already implemented.

Comment: @ElHoss It's a preexisting project, so changing it all to something different would be problematic. Do you have an example of it actually being done? Which answer do you mean? The answers on the linked post seem to me to be about wrapping the callback 'behind the scenes' rather than changing what's used in the async interface definitions.

Comment: And how does MyCallback look like?

Comment: @ElHoss broadly along the lines of `public interface MyCallback {default void onFailure(Throwable t){showInfoBoxWithError();}}`

Comment: MyCallback should extend AsyncCallback

Comment: @ElHoss my bad missed that when writing the comment. It does extend it in the actual code.